# Django webapp creating 2 profiles when a user signs up

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a django webapp after creating a view for the signup page, if i go ahead and signup two profiles are created instead of one.

i have tried redirecting to different pages but the problem still persists.

this is the view i created

```
def signup(request):
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("Signup view called")
        
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        password2 = request.POST["password2"]
        
        if password == password2:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request, "Email Taken")
                return redirect("signup")
            elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request, "Username Taken")
                return redirect("signup")
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
                user.save()
                
                #log user in and redirect to settings page
                
                #create Profile object for the new user
                user_model = User.objects.get(username=username)
                new_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user_model)
                new_profile.save()
                return redirect("signup")
        else:
            messages.info(request, "Password Not Matching")
            return redirect("signup")
    else:
        return render(request, "signup.html")
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but ideally a `Profile` model should have a one-to-one relation with the `User`. Yours seems to be a one-to-many.

Comment: Check if you don't already have signals defined in you code that creates profile automatically. If not try to use signals instead following this docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals to prevent duplicates